# GraphQL query returns only 3 items

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS to develop a website, i used a plugin `gatsby-source-medium` to query medium so i can get posts and no matter what i do, it always returns 3 items.

my query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allMediumPost(limit: 100000) {
    nodes {
      id
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMediumPost": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "8238affb-bcf6-5867-a45c-c5483b3a2225",
          "createdAt": "2023-12-03"
        },
        {
          "id": "2acbcb1d-e436-541d-b627-35feaae4db0c",
          "createdAt": "2023-10-28"
        },
        {
          "id": "0c0797bb-ab94-532c-87f1-945f2e874dd8",
          "createdAt": "2023-10-28"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I have tried using rss and axios, but it doesn't return the thumbnail and its causing some part of the site to break.

I also increased the limit.

is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another solution using the RSS feed.

Install the `gatsby-source-rss-feed` dependency (I'm using version 1.2.2).

Configure the package, pointing it to the RSS feed.

`gatsby-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    // Site stuff goes here.
  },
  plugins: [
   {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-rss-feed`,
      options: {
        url: `https://medium.com/feed/@desciafrica`,
        name: "RSS",
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

You'll have new content in GraphQL which you can use to access the RSS data.

`src/pages/home.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../layouts"

export default function Index({ data }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <p>List of RSS posts:</p>
      <ul>
        {data.allFeedRss.nodes.map((node) => (
          <li>
            <a href={node.link}><strong>{node.title}</strong></a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allFeedRss {
      nodes {
        id
        link
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

That will pull through the most recent ten posts from the feed (in the correct order!).

[image]

Comment: I am trying this out now, it does not provide the thumbnails attached to the posts, but i will try to extract it, let's see how that goes. thank you very much @datawookie

Comment: this works. not exactly what i need, but i was able to gain access to 10 most recent posts, plus i was able to extract the images i need from the encoded object. Thank you very much, i hosted on vercel, you can check the blog page. [link] (https://desciafrica.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be an artefact of the Medium site that you are targeting.

Here's my setup. In `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    // Site stuff goes here.
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-medium`,
      options: {
        username: `@impure`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

And in `packages.json` I have specified the latest version of `gatsby-source-medium`. I'm using Gatsby 5.12.5.

This is my GraphQL query:

```
query MediumQuery {
  allMediumPost {
    nodes {
      id
      createdAt
      virtuals {
        previewImage {
          imageId
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Medium site that you are targeting is specified via the `username` option in `gatsby-config.js`.

**Member's Only Site** If I target a *members only* site (like https://medium.com/@godfreythegreat) then I get data for only 4 posts (and those posts seem to be randomly selected from the site's feed).

**Public Site** If I look at a *public* site (like https://medium.com/javarevisited) then I get data for the 15 *most recent* posts in the feed.

The GraphQL query above will pull through the preview image. For example, here are the first couple of results I get from the GraphQL applied to https://medium.com/javarevisited:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMediumPost": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "1c01e905-9c7f-5958-8c72-d77462796e24",
          "createdAt": "2023-12-29",
          "virtuals": {
            "previewImage": {
              "imageId": "1*6RZCG2HX-sRaNto4lBNjgw.jpeg"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "5246a8ea-9bfd-553e-b8e0-6c0edfac79ff",
          "createdAt": "2024-01-17",
          "virtuals": {
            "previewImage": {
              "imageId": "1*3sdgyZv20p9RfVjZwCSjDQ.jpeg"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

To get the image corresponding to one of those IDs you just tack it onto the end of https://miro.medium.com/v2/. For example, https://miro.medium.com/v2/1*6RZCG2HX-sRaNto4lBNjgw.jpeg.

[image]

Take a look at [this](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/content-from-medium/) to see how Medium content can be introduced into a Gatsby view via a GraphQL query.

Comment: This is still not working for me, the account uses the `medium.com/@username` format but still only returns 3 results. I have updated my dependencies but it is still not working and I need to get all the posts. Plus they are random. Is there anything else i can try?

Comment: What Medium site are you pulling data from?

Comment: https://desciafrica.medium.com/